# How do I call a function and pass a variable with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something like

```
<button onclick="editUser('<?=id?>')">
```

I have a jquery function that updates the database with Ajax, but trying to tell the function which Id to update.

Comment: What does/doesn't work?

Comment: What is that template language you're using for `<?=id?>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the HTML something like this instead:

```
<button id="myButton" data-id="12345678">
```

When your page loads you'd do:

```
$("#myButton").click(editUser);
```

Then in `editUser()`

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
```

Your function now knows the ID you're interested in.